# In Our project build is getting failed and error is showing fatal error: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: javascript, html, ios, react-native

Our Project is Upgraded on Latest version of react-native. After running project for iOS on terminal iOS build is getting failed and below error is showing on terminal.
fatal error: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found.

project is Running fine on Xcode and build is getting succeeded but not able to debugging code on metro or debugger is not opened after project is running on x-code.

Here I attached screenshot of errors.[error screenshot of image [Xcode image of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raT6W.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtmXN.jpg)

We are trying solution belonging to build issue and using below command

> pod init
> pod install
> still Not getting proper solution.

We are also compare pod file with other and also changed accordingly and deleted pod folder and podfile.lock but not yet resolved.

I was also added below target in podfile
target 'MyNewTarget' do
inherit! :complete
end